# How to transition something to fullscreen without knowing size and position?

Tags: css

I have images that I would like to transition ot fullscale by moving and scaling it.

I could check the size and pos with javascript, apply

```
{
   position: absolute;
   width: "from js";
   height: "from js";
   top: "from js"
   left: "from js"
   transition: width .3s, height .3s, top .3s, left .3s
}
```

and then apply

```
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0
}
```

but is there some cleaner, css only way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the images fullscreen?

Comment: It's not an image, it's a div with an image and a bunch of other stuff. I also want it to transition to fullscreen from it's original location

Comment: What do you mean by "transition to full screen"? Sorry but I am not that good at English

Comment: Do you mean like an overlay. the one which covers full screen when you click it

Comment: You can use the HTML5 full screen API to make a specific node full screen, but that means you'll have to dabble with JS. At one point I've also [written a lightbox plugin](https://github.com/terrymun/Fluidbox) that does what you want to do, but it only works with images—you can however repurpose the code for positioning/calculations to do what you intend to.

Comment: @WaisKamal no problem, a transition is like an animation, the tricky part is I don't know the initial size of the screen.

Comment: @Terry interesting, what technique are you using?

Comment: For the plugin I used a combination of JS + CSS. It's not possible to tween an image/element to 100% viewport size without knowing it's computed dimensions (which is not accessible using CSS)